# Which verse of Padma purana and Narasimha purana claims Chaitanya Mahaprabhu is Krishna/Vishnu Himself?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, padma-purana, chaitanya

[This](http://gosai.com/writings/the-divinity-of-sri-caitanya-mahaprabhu-0) website provides many evidences to prove *the divinity of Caitanya Mahaprabhu*.

Verse from *Padma purana*:

> yatrayogesvarah saksad
>   yogi-cintyo **janardanah
>   caitanya** vapur aste vai
>   sandranandatmakah
>
> kaleh prathama-sandhyayam
>   gaurangotham mahi-tale
>   bhagirathi-tate ramye
>   bhavisyami saci-sutah
>
> Meaning: The Supreme Personality, Janardana, who is the object of the yogis' meditation, who saves the devotees from various sufferings, and who is the master of all yogic practices, who is always full of divine transcendental ecstasy and bliss, will advent in **His own divine form of Sri Caitanya.**
>
> I shall appear on this earth in the first part of Kali-yuga in a beautiful place on the bank of the Bhagirathi. I shall have a golden form, and I shall take birth as the son of Saci.

and from *Narasimha purana*:

> satye daitya-kuladhi-nasa-samaye
>   simhordhva-martyakrtis
>   tretayam dasa-kandharam
>   paribhavan rameti namakrtih
>   gopalan paripalayan vraja-pure
>   bharam haran dvapare
>   gaurangah priya-kirtanah
>   **kali-yuge caitanya-nama prabhuh**
>
> Meaning: The Supreme Personality of Godhead who in the Satya-yuga appeared as a half-man, half-lion to cure a terrible disease that had ravaged the daityas, and who in the Treta-yuga appeared as a person named Rama (Lord Ramacandra), a person who defeated the ten- headed Demon Ravana, and who in the Dvapara-yuga removed the earth's burden, and protected the Gopa (cowherd men) people of Vraja-pura, will appear again in the Kali-yuga. His form will be golden, He will delight in chanting the Lord's holy names, and **His name will be Caitanya**.

However, the above highlights explicitly use the word *Chaitanya* but that site didn't give exact verse number. So, *Which verse of Padma purana and Narasimha purana claims Chaitanya Mahaprabhu is Krishna/Vishnu Himself?*

Comment: Hari bol.. Hari bol

Comment: See related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15495/2790 See my comment there.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa Does ISKCON-aites believe those verses even now?

Comment: Yes, not only members of ISKCON but all the Gaudiya Vaishnavas even today believe those verses to be true, because those verses are contained in the books written by some authors, and were quoted from the Puranas and other scriptures' manuscripts that existed in the past. It is well known that many manuscripts of many Hindu scriptures got lost. Today we also have books of Ramanuja, Madhva, and other authors who lived centuries ago, and in their books there are many verses that don't appear in the extant manuscripts of the scriptures.

Comment: @brahma yeah even I read that those verses don't appear in scriptures now.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa Btw, Chaitanya's original name was Gauranga, so why do they link these verses with Chaitanya? (no offence)

Comment: There is no such a thing as "original name". All those names are equally important, and refer to Sri Caitanya.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to which verses claim this; Evidence So far, suggests that None of the verses claim it, but i hope to be proven wrong.

https://www.mahakavya.com/padma-puran-english/ provides an English index whereby "Caitanya" does not appear, nor does "Bhagirathi" appear. Same with browsing chapter headings for the claims via an internet archive upload of 2021, they are so far, unsuccessful to prove the claim.

Narasimha Purana in English can likewise be found via an Internet archive .com upload in 2020 but unfortunately both itself & Scribd's index is only in sanskrit rather than in English. https://archive.org/details/narasimha-purana-english

A wish for all compilers of alleged sources; please give a little more evidence or don't seed doubt in the first place. I.e. Kausiki publisher within google-books has no slokas at all. The web is already saturated copying bonafide lists of puranic evidence that are muddied by unproven additions. Edit: especially explained here https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/7/9/38/
Whereby Caitanya specifically must appear in a hidden way in Kali yugas and will never call himself Krishna, it is up to the indirect foreseuthing of the existing vedas and the sages to decide from parental names, the place of birth and the actions in life.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).